# Javascript alert with parameter

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters, alert

I'm trying to make a function in javascript and pass in the parameter "name", then when the user clicks on a photo, an alert will say something like "this photo was taken in ____"

```
<img src="photos/PhotoVersailles.jpg" onclick="photoWhere(Versailles)" style="width:100%">

<script type="text/javascript">
function photoWhere(name)
    {
        alert("This photo was taken in "+name+".");
    }
</script>
```

Why isn't my attempt working?

Comment: `onclick="photoWhere(Versailles)"` should be: `onclick="photoWhere('Versailles')"`

Comment: `onclick="photoWhere('Versailles')"` you forgot to wrap `Versailles` in quotes.

Comment: You need to actually ask a question if you want an answer.

Comment: What is the Question.?

Comment: The question is why isn't his or her attempt working.

Answer (score 2):

Try `'Versailles'` when passing as parameter

```js
function photoWhere(name) {
  alert("This photo was taken in " + name + ".");
}
```

```html
<img src="photos/PhotoVersailles.jpg" onclick="photoWhere('Versailles')" alt="not found" style="width:100%">
```

Comment: You have to see it uses " ' ' " or ' " " '

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong, change your alert to:

```
var nameStr = "This photo was taken in "+name+".";
alert(nameStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```js
function photoWhere(Pic) { var _pic = Pic.name; _pic = "This photo was taken in "+_pic+"." alert(_pic); }
```

```html
<img src="photos/PhotoVersailles.jpg" onclick="photoWhere(this)" 
name="Versailles" style="width:50%">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer that is mostly code, please explain it a little bit.